# Deviding Django application (social network) to Django Frontend and RESTfull API

Tags: django, web-applications, web.py

I'm writing Django application (social network) and thinking about dividing monolithic project to two projects: UI and API. For example, Django will be used only to render pages, interacting with and taking data from API, written on web.py.

Pros are following:

1. I can develop and test API independently.
2. In the future, other UI can appears (mobile, for example), it will require service.
3. I plan to outsource web UI developing, so, if my application will have two modules, I can provide outside only UI one, not sharing logic of application.

Cons are following:

1. I'm working alone, and developing two projects are harder, then one.
2. I will not be able to use cool Django admin panel. I will need to write my own.
3. web.py is more low-level comparing with Django.

It's like a brain dump, but I will be really appreciated if you share your experience in creating web application with UI module and independent API module.

**Update** (more specific question, as Mike asked)

*What Python framework will you use for creating REST API of social network, which can be used by different client applications? Is using web.py that returns JSON only and rendering it by Django for web is good idea?*

Thanks, 
Boris.

Comment: I think you should pose a more specific question, but very interested in following this conversation.

Comment: You're right, @MikeScott, made it more specific.

Comment: I am wondering if it would be a good idea to just use Javascript on the frontend completely. In some process you have to use it anyway and if your data is coming from an API completely why not using Javascript directly without even going through Django. I think this is also a good idea performance wise, since all your code is static in the frontend. You could use one of the many JS MVC Frameworks.

Comment: @Torsten, as I see it now, Django will take not only generation of static web pages, but also i18n stuff. Can i18n be simply implemented in JS MVC Frameworks?

Comment: @Marboni There are solutions to do i18n in Javascript. Depending on what framework you want to use you have to search of course if it exists. I didn't used it myself yet, though I can see just by a short search that there are multiple general solutions, most of them using gettext as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in a situation similar to yours. I ended up writing both, the UI and the API part in Django. Currently, I am serving them both out of the same process/project. You mentioned you wanted to be able to outsource the UI development, but do hear me out.

In the meantime, I have used django-piston to implement the RESTful front end, but a bit of preparation went into it:

1. Encapsulate all DB and ORM accesses into a library. You can do that either for your entire project, or on an app by app basis. The library is not just a low-level wrapper around your DB accesses, but also can be for higher-level 'questions', such as "all_comments_posted_by_friends()" or something. This accomplishes two things:

   1. You can call your pre-canned queries from UI views as well as API views without having to re-implement them in multiple places.
   2. You will later be able to replace some - if not all - of the underlying DB logic if you ever feel like going to a NoSQL database, for example, to some other distributed storage model. You can setup your entire app of this ahead of time, without actually having to worry about the complicated details of this right at the start.
2. The authentication layer for the API was able to accept an HMAC/token based header for programmatic access and normal Django auth. I setup the views in such a way that they would render plain JSON for the programmatic clients (based on content-type), and would render the data structure in HTML (with clickable links and clickable docstrings) if browsed by a human from a browser. This makes it possible that the API is fully explorable and clickable by a human without having to read any docs, while at the same time it can be easily processed by a client just via JSON.

On effect, the database layer I build serves as the internal API. This same database layer can be used from multiple applications, multiple processes, if you wish to do so. The UI views and the REST views were both implemented in Django. They can either be in the same process or in separate processes (as long as they have access to the same database right now).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @jbrendel! Please, clarify this with example: "This makes it possible that the API is fully explorable and clickable by a human without having to read any docs"

Comment: For this it's important that you don't need any prior knowledge about the URI patterns or where to find resources. EVERYTHING should be discoverable simply by following links.So, you shouldn't have to know that your messages are at /foo/messages, while your users are at /bar/users. Or that you need to do /foo/messages/user/smith to get all the messages of a user, vs. /bar/users/smith/messages to get  them. When you have to remember all of this and know this ahead

Comment: Sorry, I took to long editing my comment. Here it is in full:

You shouldn't need any prior knowledge about the URI patterns or where to find resources. EVERYTHING should be discoverable simply by following links.

You should just go to "/" and be able to follow links to everything: See links to top-level lists, click there, see list of items, click on item, see list of attributes and links (not just IDs!) of anything else that refers to/from it. I also provide docstrings in the HTML output when a human browses, introspect input forms and summarize that to let them know what can be POSTed.